# Unix - how to fetch files based on the part of a filename that is date

Tags: shell, shell-script, files

Say I have files say like

```
AA_XX_20111208
AA_XX_20111207
AA_XX_20111206
AA_XX_20111205
AA_XX_20111204
AA_XX_20111203
```

So using the date part,
how can i fetch previous 2 month files ?

For e.g. this month is February,
I must fetch all files relating to January and December.
and for month of March, i must fetch files of January and February
This has to happen each month.

Eg. for month of February i need files of Dec and Jan

```
AA_XX_20121208
AA_XX_20121207
AA_XX_20121206
```

...so on

```
AA_XX_20130108
AA_XX_20130107
AA_XX_20130106
```

...so on

Comment: Use `find (1)`.

Comment: Is "fetch" supposed to mean something?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have GNU date, this function will get you all the dates for the previous 2 months:

```
dates_in_previous_two_months () { 
    for month_delta in 0 1; do
        # get the last day of a previous month
        day=$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-01) -$month_delta month -1 day" +%Y%m%d)
        until [[ $day == *00 ]]; do
            echo $day
            ((day--))
        done
    done
}
```

For any day in the month of February 2013, this returns:

```
20130131
20130130
20130129
[... and so on until ...]
20121203
20121202
20121201
```

In March it will return dates from `20130228` to `20130101`

You could use it like:

```
for date in $(dates_in_previous_two_months); do
    "fetch" AA_XX_$date
done
```

or

```
dates_in_previous_two_months | xargs -I{} "fetch" AA_XX_{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` command. The following command will list down all files modified within last 60 days

```
find . -name 'AA_XX_*' -mtime -60
```

Here is shell script for achieving what you want, but I would agree that it's not a clean solution. I, myself, don't like this clumsy code, but then it will work for you, for time being

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

YEAR=`date +%Y`
MONTH=`date +%m`
DATE=`date +%d`

if [ $MONTH = 01 ]; then
    OLDEST=`expr $YEAR - 1`11010000
    NEWEST=`expr $YEAR - 1`12312359
elif [ $MONTH = 02 ]; then
    OLDEST=`expr $YEAR - 1`12010000
    echo $YEAR
    NEWEST="$YEAR"01312359
else
    case $MONTH in
            03)
            OLDEST=$YEAR0`expr $MONTH - 2`010000
            if [ $YEAR%4 = 0 ]; then
                    DATE=29
            else
                    DATE=28
            fi
            NEWEST=$YEAR0`expr $MONTH - 1`"$DATE"2359;;

            04|06|09|11)
            OLDEST=$YEAR0`expr $MONTH - 2`010000
            NEWEST=$YEAR0`expr $MONTH - 1`312359;;

            07|08|10|12)
            OLDEST=$YEAR0`expr $MONTH - 2`010000
            NEWEST=$YEAR0`expr $MONTH - 1`302359;;
        esac
fi

echo $OLDEST
echo $NEWEST

touch -t $OLDEST oldest
touch -t $NEWEST newest

find . -name 'AA_XX_*' -newer oldest ! -newer newest > temp.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.But i actually need the files by the date part ie. '20130108' ,not by the modified timestamp.

Comment: But still this command seems very helpful,thanks a lot.Realising only now.

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvotes? If the solution will fail in some cases, I would like to know, so that I can fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
cp source/AA_XX_$(date -d "2 months ago" +%04Y%02m)* source/AA_XX_$(date -d "1 month ago" +%04Y%02m)* destination/
```

Comment: That won't work on the 29th, 30th or 31th of March, or more generally any day of the month that has no corresponding day in the month before (or 2 month ago). See the [GNU date documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings) for a work-around. Note that `-d` is GNU specific.

Answer (score 0):

This month with the year prepended is `$(date +%Y%m)`. Last month is `previous_month_1=$(date -d '1 month ago' +%Y%m)` with GNU date (i.e. on non-embedded Linux or Cygwin), and the month before is `previous_month_2=$(date -d '2 months ago' +%Y%m)`. on other implementations, they're given by

```
this_month=$(date +%Y%m)
case $this_month in
  *01) previous_month_1=$((this_month-89)); previous_month_2=$((previous_month-1));;
  *02) previous_month_1=$((this_month-1)); previous_month_2=$((previous_month-89));;
  *) previous_month_1=$((this_month-1)); previous_month_2=$((previous_month-1));;
esac
```

Now, to match all existing files dated from the previous two months:

```
fetch "AA_XX_$previous_month_1"?? "AA_XX_$previous_month_2"??
```

(Replace `fetch` by the command you want to run on those files.) If a month may have no matching file, the pattern will be left unchanged:

```
filter_month () {
  case $1 in *'??') return;; esac
  fetch "$@"
}
filter_month "$previous_month_1"??
filter_month "$previous_month_2"??
```

If you want to fetch all files corresponding to the days of that month, you'll either need some GNU date magic (not described here) or some leap year logic.

```
filter_month () {
  case $1 in
    *0[13578]|*1[02]) n=31;;
    *0[469]|*11) n=30;;
    *0002) if [ $((${1%????} %4)) -eq 0 ]; then n=29; else n=28; fi;;
    *02) if [ $((${1%??} %4)) -eq 0 ]; then n=29; else n=28; fi;;
  esac
  while [ $n -gt 0 ]; do
    d=$n
    if [ $d -lt 10 ]; then d=0$d; fi
    fetch "AA_XX_$1$d"
  fi
}
filter_month "$previous_month_1"
filter_month "$previous_month_2"
```